# Simple Javascript Help Request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm after a little help with some JS not behaving.  I would like to make it so that I can pass an some JavaScript to affect the end URL destination as below: The end destination being (`delete-page.php?id=1`)

```
<a href ="javascript:deletemessage('id=1')">Delete Page </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function deletemessage(url) {
  $.msgbox("Are you Sure you would like to delete this page", {
    type: "confirm",
    buttons: [{
      type: "submit",
      value: "No"
    }, {
      type: "submit",
      value: "Yes"
    }]
  }, function(result) {
    if (result == "Yes") {
      window.location.href = "delete-page.php(URL)";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:
`window.location.href = "delete-page.php(URL)";`

with: `window.location.href = "delete-page.php?" + url;`

Comment: Cheers! Thanks heaps, I knew I was close. Really appreciated!

Comment: Should actually be `'delete-page.php?' + url`